# Noob question: Class and instance methods in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a function called update_status inside my comments_controller.rb:

```
def update_status
  @comment.relative_value = @comment.points_up - @comment.points_down
  randomize!
end
```

Where `@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])`

Because of the way I've set up the website, I want to be able to call c.update_status for any comment c. For example, in my posts_controller, I want to be able to do this:

```
def show
  @posts = Post.order('trending_value DESC').page(params[:page]).per(5)
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @post.comments

  @comments.each do |c| #TODO: FIX
    c.update_status
    c.save
  end
end
```

How do I get this to work? I keep getting undefined method error for `# < Comment >`. Do I have to do `def self.update_status`? That didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're confusing a helper function update_status() in your controller with a member function on the comment instance.  You can make your controller code work by passing the comment to the helper function as an argument:

```
def update_status(comment)
  comment.relative_value = comment.points_up - comment.points_down
  comment.save
  randomize!
end

def show
  @posts = Post.order('trending_value DESC').page(params[:page]).per(5)
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @post.comments

  @comments.each do {|c| update_status(c) }
end
```

You could also add this as a member function on the Comment class itself, like this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  def update_status
    update_attributes(:relative_value => points_up - points_down)
    randomize!
  end
end

def show
  @posts = Post.order('trending_value DESC').page(params[:page]).per(5)
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @post.comments

  @comments.each do {|c| c.update_status }
end
```